# How to list all images used on a specific page?

Tags: plugin-development, images, pages, urls

How do I list all the image(s) used on a specific WordPress page. I would like it to include the following if possible,

- Url to image
- Name of image
- Url to thumbnail of the image

[Edit]
I would like to use WordPress itself to get the images, not use something like CURL and extract image urls. Also note this is back-end for a plugin.

[Edit 2]
I need to not only get images within the content of the page, but also images from the theme like a logo in the header, etc. Basically, all images that are on the entire page is what I'm trying to get

Comment: Questions in the form of "please do this for me" rarely receive answers.  If you show an example of what you tried, where you researched a possible answer, etc you will find folks more willing to assist.

Comment: @jdm2112 Hello, I have googled and done my research on this but so far I am unable to find anything that pulls image's urls from a specific page in WordPress. I do always try to find the answer myself before asking here. I would also like to add that this is not a "do this for me" question but more of a how do I go about accomplishing this

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the front-end or in the back-end, via a plugin for example.

Comment: Backend (This is for a plugin), I will update my question

Answer (score 1):

The WP function `get_attached_media()` should provide the info you need.

If used in this way...

```
$media = get_attached_media( 'image' );
```

... the `$media` var should contain the wp_post objects for all attached images.

Function documentation in the WP Codex:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_media/

Comment: Thank you for your response, I understand that this pulls images from the content but how do I get images outside the content (like logo's within the header and images used by the theme)?